# mapkit addAnnotations crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I have a UITabBarController and a "Map" tab on it.
The Map tab is associated with my custom UIViewController and it has a MKMapView on it.
When I'm currently selecting another tab, and when I do tap on the Map tab, iPhone4 with iOS4.3.1 crashes with a crash log like this:

What can I do to prevent this crash?
What's wrong with my code?

```
  0   MapKit                        0x3501fc20 _contains(objc_object*, MKQuadTrieNode*) + 16
  1   MapKit                        0x3501fc00 -[MKQuadTrie contains:] + 12
  2   MapKit                        0x3501f9f2 -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotation:] + 218
  3   MapKit                        0x3501f8e6 -[MKAnnotationContainerView addAnnotations:] + 102
  4   MapKit                        0x3501f856 -[MKMapView addAnnotations:] + 42

  5   MyApp                         0x000075d6 0x1000 + 26070

  6   UIKit                         0x3559ff08 -[UIViewController view] + 104
  7   UIKit                         0x355dd1d4 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:transition:shouldSetSelected:] + 60
  8   UIKit                         0x355dd186 -[UITabBarController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:] + 26
  9   UIKit                         0x355dca2c -[UITabBarController _setSelectedViewController:] + 180
  10  UIKit                         0x35661ce4 -[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] + 8
  11  UIKit                         0x35661be0 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 220
  12  CoreFoundation                0x3593656a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
  13  UIKit                         0x35585ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
  14  UIKit                         0x35585e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
  15  UIKit                         0x35661a84 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 264
  16  CoreFoundation                0x3593656a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
  17  UIKit                         0x35585ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
  18  UIKit                         0x35585e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
  19  UIKit                         0x35585e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32
  20  UIKit                         0x35585b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350
  21  UIKit                         0x355bfbd2 -[UIControl sendActionsForControlEvents:] + 10
  22  UIKit                         0x3566180e -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 74
  23  CoreFoundation                0x3593656a -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 18
  24  UIKit                         0x35585ec2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 78
  25  UIKit                         0x35585e62 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
  26  UIKit                         0x35585e34 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 32
  27  UIKit                         0x35585b86 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 350
  28  UIKit                         0x3558641c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 336
  29  UIKit                         0x35584bee -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 362
  30  UIKit                         0x35584568 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 256
  31  UIKit                         0x3556d30c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 292
  32  UIKit                         0x3556cc4c _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
```

My custom UIViewController does this on viewDidLoad:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;

    // some [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver....] snipped

    [ self.mapView addAnnotations: **my annotations** ];
}
```

I think the 5th line in the stack trace is viewDidLoad,
so the crash must be(I think..) due to my annotations. I had 300-400 annotations when it crashed.
My annotations has a coordinate accessor like this:

```
- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D  coordinate_;
    coordinate_.latitude  = [ self.lat doubleValue ];
    coordinate_.longitude = [ self.lng doubleValue ];
    return coordinate_;
}
```

Where self.lat,lng is defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* lat;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* lng;
```

It's an app already on AppStore and I don't know how to reproduce the crash, it just doesn't crash now, so all I have is the crash log and my source code.
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens with the array of annotations after you call addAnnotations:? Perhaps it gets released it before all annotations (you say you have a few hundreds of them) can be added to the view?

Comment: Is the "adding to the view" async? There are a few places where I call `[self.mapView removeAnnotations: self.mapView.annotations]; [self.mapView addAnnotations: **my annotations**];` so that might be *another* bug? (I wrote *another* because I found an iOS bug by myself), will answer myself after this..

Comment: I found that adding annotions with `( lat <= -86 || 86 <= lat )` makes iphone crash.
Reproduced on iPhone Simulator 4.2

lat: 85 lived, but 86 crashed, lat: -85 lived but -86 crashed.

I use a custom MKAnnotationView, so the size of the custom view might change the limit (lat:86) but I haven't tried that.

Comment: it quite possibly is asynchronous, otherwise adding hundreds of annotations would freeze the app. Perhaps some of your users have many more annotations than most? Try adding a lot of annotations (like 500) - maybe you'll be able to reproduce the crash.