# App Crashes if AddAnnotations doesn't finish

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation

I have an Application, which is a SplitViewController that has a master view on the left and the detail view on the right. One of the views (Branch Finder) is a Map view that loads a series of Annotations to the Map.

If I let the annotations load before switching to any other view (loading the annotations take takes all of 1 second) then everything is fine. However, if the user quickly switches off the Branch Finder view, whilst the annotations are being loaded, then the App will crash with the following notice:

> [BranchFinder_iPad respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x807d230

Now, my thoughts are that the deallocated instance would refer to the Array (declared in the header of the view) that contains all the annotations being released and set to nil when the user leaves the BranchFinder_iPad view. This is the array that is being passed to the addAnnotations method.

```
[self.mapView addAnnotations:branchSites];
```

Has anyone else encountered an issue where leaving a view, mid-way in the add allocations and a crash occurs if the user moves to another view.

Just to clarify:

- If I wait for the annotations to load, switching to any other view causes no problem.
- I did have a custom annotation view, but I stripped that out of my code (to eliminate it from the mix). Doing this has not changed anything.
- I have looked elsewhere for help on this issue, but a lot of the view tutorials regarding map views are single view only, so this issue hasn't arisen.
- I have found a vaguely similar issue @ the following: [mapkit addAnnotations crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687451/mapkit-addannotations-crashes)
- And finally, I have just made the jump to x-code 4. I think some of my problems are just because I'm relearning some of the things I should know.

Regards,
Nathan A

PS: I wanted to attach an image to this, but am having trouble. I don't have the reputation points to do it natively, and my workplace doesn't allow me access to any image hosting portals. I will endeavour to add an image later today.

Answer (score 3):

Hey anyone who reads this.

I basically performed a rookie mistake here - for the MKMapView in my application, I had to set the delegate to nil as part of the deallocation routine within my view. THe apple documentation makes mention of this in the below document:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html

For the relevant section:

> Before releasing an MKMapView object for which you have set a delegate, remember to set that object’s delegate property to nil. One place you can do this is in the dealloc method where you dispose of the map view.

Not having this was only causing an issue if I switched to another view AND if the MKMapView was still being referenced in executing code, such as the addAnnotations routine.